# How to load static page in PWA if it doesn't exist in dynamic cache

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My PWA is using the web first caching strategy.

If the request is successful, it is stored in dynamic cache with url as a key.

If the request fails, service worker looks if that request is stored in the dynamic cache and returns it.

That part works fine, I can visit all the pages that I've visited online when I'm offline, the problem is that I would like to return static html page with a button that leads to homepage when I have nothing in the dynamic cache.

I want to do that because I get stuck on offline page if I try to visit page that wasn't dynamically cached yet because there is no browser back button in full-screen mode.

My service worker code:

```
event.respondWith(
     fetch(event.request)
          .then(function(res) {
              return caches.open('eyewit')
            .then(function(cache) {
              // console.log( 'Goes to cache: '  + event.request.url );
              // console.log( 'DYNAMIC' );
              let url = event.request.url;

              // dont cache maps
              if (url.indexOf('google') == -1) {
                  // store request to dynamic cache
                  cache.put(url, res.clone());
              } 
              return res;
            })
   })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // look for value in cache if request fails
    console.log( 'From cache' );
    // I would like to return static page ./offline.html if there is nothing in cache
    // with key event.request, if value exist return it instead
    // caches.match returns promise
    return caches.match(event.request);
  })
);
```

I've tried doing this but it didnt work because caches.match(event.request) returns promise:

```
.catch(function(err) {
     // return value from dynamic cache if exists
     if(caches.match(event.request)) {
          return caches.match(event.request);
     } else {
         // serve static page
         return caches.open('static_cache')
          .then((cache) => {
            return cache.match('offline.html');
          });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If caches.match returns a promise you need to wait for the response

```
.catch(function(err) {
     // return value from dynamic cache if exists
     return caches.match(event.request).then(function(result) {
          // If no match, result will be undefined
          if (result) {
               return result;
          } else {
               return caches.open('static_cache')
                 .then((cache) => {
                     return cache.match('offline.html');
               });
          }
     });
```